# Webform to content type

Tags: 8, webforms

In the Webform module version 8.x-5.0-rc27 there isn't the tab to add a webform to a certain content type.

Is this intentional? If not, is there a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The Webform (node) References tab should still be working as expected in rc27.

[image: Webform (node) References tab]

Comment: hmm the issue might have to do with the fact that i am using Thunder, the d8 distribution for publishers. Not sure though. THanks for your fast response